# Is there a way for 2 scripts to write to the same file?

Tags: python, excel, while-loop

I have limited python experience, but determined to learn. I am trying to create a script that would write some data inputs to excel until stopped. It is very straightforward when a single person is using it but the problem is that 2 people will be using it at once.

I am thinking about making it simple and just having 2 exact same scripts running at the same time, but the problem comes in when the file is going to be saved. If I have two files being saved with the same name, one is going to overwrite the other and the data will be lost. Is there a way to have the scripts create files with different names without having to manually change the code? (This would eventually be scaled to up to 20 computers running it)

The loop looks like:

```
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
s1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

data = []
while user != '0':
    user = input('Scan ID Badge: ')
    data.append(user)
    order = input('Scan order: ')
    data.append(order)
    item = input('Scan item barcode: ')
    data.append(item)

    for i in range(len(data)):
        s1.write(row,i,data[i])

    wb.save('OrderData.xls')
    data = []
    row += 1
```

Comment: use a directory depending on the username (using `os.expanduser("~")` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a tabular form of data storage anyways, you could switch to a real database and on interval create an excel-like summary of the db file.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all of the users using this script will be using machines with different network names, you could include the computer name in the XLS name:

```py
import platform

filename = 'AssociateEfficiencyTemp-' + platform.node() + '.xls'
# ...
wb.save(filename)
```

(You can also use `getpass.getuser()` to (try and) get the username of the user running the script.)

You can then write another script that reads all of the separate files (`glob.glob('AssociateEfficiencyTemp-*.xls')` etc.) and combines them.

(I would suggest using another format than .xls for the intermediary files though, [such as plain text files of JSON lines](http://jsonlines.org/).)

Comment: careful about that on multi-user computers (servers): several users can run the script on the same node

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sure. I added a note about using the username too. However, if I'm guessing right, this is a script run on several workstations on a shared drive of some sort.

Comment: Correct, it will be running on a shared drive